# Hide search bar in application menu Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I would like to remove / hide the search bar in the menu. Is there any extension to hide the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no extension that would allow to remove the search bar from the activities overview or the full screen applications menu.

Comment: Is there any extension available for removing the complete left bottom menu / application button?

Comment: That can be achieved in dconf-editor. Alternatively, install Dash To dock, which exposes these settings through a graphical interface. The settings of Dash To Dock apply also to Ubuntu dock. When done, disable Dash to dock and enable Ubuntu Dock to revert to using Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: Thank you, that is working. It can be found in dconf location `org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock` and the setting is called `show-show-apps-button`. Just put the setting on "false" and the menu is gone.